# Scrape table from each option in drop down menu python

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, drop-down-menu, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape all the data from this website:
http://www.dartsdatabase.co.uk/PlayerStats.aspx?statKey=1&pg=7

However, I do not know how to iterate through the **'stat'** drop-down menu. Each of these options contains a table I need to scrape.

So far I have the following code which lists the options and values associated with each element in the drop-down list:

```
url = 'http://www.dartsdatabase.co.uk/PlayerStats.aspx'

response = requests.get(url).text

soup = BeautifulSoup(response,"lxml")

drop = soup.find('select',{'name':'stat'}).findAll("option")

options = []

val = []

for i in range(0,len(drop)):

    options.append(drop[i].text)

    val.append(drop[i]['value'])
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make POST requests altering the `stat` param. You can gather the appropriate values from the page `value` attribute of the options

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

data = {
  'nameSearch': '',
  'dateFrom': '02/10/2017',
  'dateTo': '02/10/2019',
  'organStat': 'All',
  'stat': '1',
  'tourns': 'All',
  'pg': '7'
}

def get_soup():
    r = s.post('http://www.dartsdatabase.co.uk/PlayerStats.aspx?statKey=1&pg=7', data=data)
    soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')  
    return soup

with requests.Session() as s:
    soup = get_soup()
    table = pd.read_html(str(soup.select_one('br + table')))[0]
    stats = [i['value'] for i in soup.select('[name="stat"] option')][1:]
    print(table)

    for i in stats:
        data['stat']=i
        soup = get_soup()
        table = pd.read_html(str(soup.select_one('br + table')))[0]
        print(table)
```

Comment: Very nice indeed.Please could you educate how did you manage to get the post request?

Comment: I used the network tab to monitor the traffic when making selections in drop down. I then used experience to guess what headers and parts of 'data' I could remove then experimented with removing most items!